# C Prints symbols then reading from file instead of characters

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
```

## Read from file and print c value

```
void skaitymas()
{
 FILE *fp = fopen("3.txt","r");
 int c,a;
 while((c=getc(fp))!=EOF)
 {

   if(c != ' ')
   {
   a = a + c; 
   printf("%c ",a);
   if(c == '\n')
   printf("\n");
   }
 }

}
```

## Main

```
int main()
{
skaitymas();
printf("\n");
system("pause");
}
```

## Input file

zodis antis plastake zvirblis aksesuaras

kompiuteris pelyte kate afganistanas lietuva

## Explanation

So I am trying to read words from file and print them out but it prints symbols instead of character. I guess `printf("%c",a)` is a problem here how can I solve it?

Comment: You didn't initialize var a and you adding values in to it.. and why are you adding and not just printing? If you will over 255?

Comment: Please explain the purpose of the line:  a = a + c;

Comment: @MahonriMoriancumer Purpose of that line is to sum chars to get word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run it, working now :

```
#include <stdio.h>

void skaitymas()
{
 FILE *fp = fopen("3.txt","r");
 char c,a='\0';
 while((c=getc(fp))!=EOF)
 {

   if(c != ' ')
   {
   //a = a + c;
   printf("%c ",c);
   if(c == '\n')
   printf("\n");
   }
 }

}

int main()
{
skaitymas();
printf("\n");
system("pause");
}
```

Comment: don't know why u did "a = a+c" // its purposeless.

Comment: I want to make variable contain whole word so that's why i made `a = a+c`

Comment: okay for that you would need logic that says until space occures you need to append that char into a char pointer or  char array.

Answer (score 0):

What is

```
a = a + c;
```

This will print first character correct but then add value of 'o'(111) in value of 'z'(122) and it keep on doing same which may overflow normal char limits, hence it prints symbols.

Edit : As you have not even initialized variable 'a', it may contain garbage value so it won't even print first character correct.

Answer (score 0):

`a = a + c` is actual sum up `a` and `c` value so it represent integer value.

To concatenate two character, use `sprintf()`.
Or,
append a char to a string buffer:

`char buf[BUF_SIZE]; // string buffer
[snip]
buf++ = a; // append a char to string buffer and increment buf pointer by 1byte.`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use

```
char a,c; // characters
```

instead of

```
int a,c;  // integers
```

And I don't get why you use a instead of just printing c

```
printf("%c",c);
```

Moreover, you loop on:

```
a = a + c;
```

So it adds the ascii value and **do not concatenate** (you will quickly read garbage, after some loops)
(if you vant to concateate a and c can't be ints or chars, or they can but the concatenation will be difficult and you will have to use more vars)